# In Jupyter notebook, how does one revert/refresh to the original notebook before any changes were made?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm forced to use jupyter notebook for a class. Somehow a code block got turned into text and now it won't run this cell. I want to revert the notebook to the original (the notebook provided by course without my programs added in) before I made *any* changes to it. How does one do this?

The only thing I could find was this at [jupyter refresh](https://learner.coursera.help/hc/en-us/articles/360004995312-Solve-problems-with-Jupyter-Notebooks)
Refresh your notebook
1. Rename your existing Jupyter Notebook within the individual notebook view
2. In the notebook view, add “?forceRefresh=true” to the end of your notebook URL
3. Reload the screen
4. You will be directed to your home Learner Workspace where you’ll see both old and new Notebook files.
5. Your Notebook lesson item will now launch to the fresh notebook.

But I'm unsure what the first two steps mean. I tried renaming and then adding “?forceRefresh=true” at the end, but that didn't help. Perhaps someone could advise? Thanks

Comment: There is no need to revert. In the menu, select Cell -> Cell type -> Code

Comment: It won't let me submit as I must have changed something else by mistake. I would like to revert to the original if you could please tell me how.

Comment: Previous versions of Jupyther notebooks are saved in the same folder, in `.ipynb_checkpoints` subfolder. If you don't have it, there is no other way to restore

Comment: The original isn't in the checkpoints unfortunately as that was the first thing I checked. How can I not revert to the original? It seems absurd really. If this were any other IDE, I could just go back and look at the original file.